# Selecting media internal to application

Tags: android

I have seen tons of examples for using the phones built in gallary app, but are there any ways to select media bundled with the app itself?

Comment: What do you mean by media bundled here? Are you are asking about list down all the drawables and mipmaps ?

Comment: https://www.androidauthority.com/how-to-build-an-image-gallery-app-718976/